# How to find an object's path with attribute values in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to use an object named 'task' in my mongodb database. a task can have one or more tasks as its children. I need to find a task which may lie down at any level of the hierarchy with its _id or other attributes values. How can I do that in mongoose or mongodb? 
My task schema will be as follows:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var Project = require(./project.js); 
    var Resource = require(./resource.js); 
    var Group = require(./group.js); 
    var Phase = require(./phase.js); 
    var Objective = require(./objective.js); 
    var Milestone = require(./milestone.js); 
    var Decision_tag = require(./decision_tag.js); 

    var createInfo = require(./plugins/createInfo); 


    var taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
      {
        title :{ type : String, unique : true, required : true,  trim :true},
        resources :[{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'Resource', required, false}], 
        groups :[{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'Group', required, false}], 
        tasks :[{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'Task', required, false}], 
        decision_tags :[{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'Decision_tag' , required : false}]

      });
    taskSchema.plugin(createInfo);


    module.exports = mongoose.model('Task' , 'taskSchema' , tasks);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the schema defined in your code above all your tasks are stored in one collection as "top-level tasks". Your hierarchy only exists as references between those tasks, so you can just query with all the normal mongoose query functionality to find your task or subtask, e.g.:

```
mongoose.model('Task').find({title: 'myTitle'});
```

the main remaining problem is probably to find/load/display the whole hiearchy of the subtask you found. Maybe it would be better to store a reference to a task's parent task instead of storing the children. Or doing both. It really depends whether you want to optimize for write or for read. Storing the parent task allows you to easily identify a top-level task (parent is emtpy).

If you never display/load a subtask without its whole hierarchy, you could also use subdocuments instead of ObjectId-references, but then querying for subtasks will be tricky.

Comment: the task can have subtasks upto 10 level deep and I have to delete or move a subtask with its _id or other attribute value. how can i do that?

Comment: these are just normal tree datastructure operations, there is nothing specific mongoose/mongo about that. Get a book or google about manipulating trees datastructures. You basically need to update the references correctly when a task is moved, or delete all depenedant tasks when a task is deleted. Recursive algorithms help here, basic computer sience. Mongoose does not solve these problems for you.